# vue3 defineEmits event to

Tags: vuejs3

i have my child component as :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="openTeleport">Add Contact</button>
  </div>   
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineEmits, ref } from 'vue';
const emits = defineEmits(['openTeleport']); 
const openTeleport = () => {
const someValue = "someValue123";
  emits('openTeleport', "someValue");
   console.log("from openTeleport", someValue)
};
</script>
```

and  i want to get the fired event openTeleport on to my parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   "someValue"
    <Child @openTeleport="handleOpenTeleport" />   
    </div>**
<script setup>

const handleOpenTeleport = (value : any) => {
 alert("hello");
 console.log('openTeleport event received'), value;
  
};
<script>
```

but event is not fired, what wrong I am doing??

Comment: I don't know if this is an error from copying, but your script tag in the parent component is not closed properly (<script> instead of </script>)

Comment: Minor syntax errors aside, the issue is not reproducible using the code given.  Check for other errors, possibly in your console, that could be preventing code execution.

Comment: [reproduction attempt](https://shorturl.at/bJNQ2) shown to be working fine in terms of event firing.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to rectify the code and managed to make it functional. Below is the modified implementation that resolves the issue. I noticed some minor adjustments that needed to be made.

In the `openTeleport` function, which is used to trigger the openTeleport event, the value passed to the emits function should be the `someValue` variable itself, not the string `"someValue"` right?.

Child component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="openTeleport">Add Contact</button>
  </div>   
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineEmits, ref } from 'vue';

const emits = defineEmits(['openTeleport']); 
const openTeleport = () => {
  const someValue = "someValue123";
  emits('openTeleport', someValue); // Passing the variable value
  console.log("from openTeleport", someValue);
};
</script>
```

Parent component

In the parent component, the value is not logged to the console correctly. You used `console.log('openTeleport event received'), value;` instead of `console.log('openTeleport event received', value);`.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Child from './Child.vue';

const handleOpenTeleport = (value : any) => {
 console.log('openTeleport event received', value);
  
};
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <Child @openTeleport="handleOpenTeleport" /> 
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also view the code on [Vue.js Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) for further reference.

Comment: main problem was event handling from child and parent components...my click button was on parent ...is there a way events can be sent to any imported component?